# How to remove Broken Link Checker widget from admin menu

Tags: multisite, widgets, wp-admin, dashboard

I'm trying to clean up the Admin [Dashboard widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API) so that only the administrator level users can see the various meta boxes, but no matter what i've tried the [Broken Link Checker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/broken-link-checker/) widget will not go away (see example code below).

I'm using **WordPress 3.1 MultiSite Network** and working with this code in the **MU plugins folder** ... not sure that matters ... i've also tried **Adminimize** plugin but that did not work for me on the widget either.

```
/* Turn off Dashboard Widgets */

if( is_admin() )
    add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets' );

function remove_dashboard_widgets() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_quick_press']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_incoming_links']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_right_now']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_plugins']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_recent_drafts']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_comments']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_secondary']);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['blc_dashboard_widget']);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers ... cordially,
Chuck Scott

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably just that your code runs before broken links checker adds the meta box. Try changing the action line to this:

```
if(is_admin()){
  add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets', 1000 );
}
```

### EDIT

To be a little more clear, the particular issue here is that the `add_action()` function is running super early compared to Broken Link Checker's add_action function. The two ways to fix that issue are to either run your code later (hooking your plugin's main functionality onto init and throwing your actions and filters into that init function), or increasing the precedence of your action (what I suggested above).

Comment: Thank you - totally worked ... i only have a couple custom functions so the priority setting of 20 did the job ... not sure if setting a priority too high like 100 or 1000 impacts load time but again, THANK YOU!

Comment: No, it wouldn't affect load time at all. That just becomes the key number for the array of actions attached to `'wp_dashboard_setup'`, so it's equally fast to use 10, 20, 1000, or 9001. The only reason to use a higher number is to make absolutely sure that your handler runs last on the hook.